# Why won't my PHP form send emails correctly?

Tags: php, html, scripting

It sends the email, but without a body, subject or anything. This is what I get:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="contact-form">
            <form action="mail.php" method="post">
                <label for="name">Name:<input type="text" id="name" class="text" /></label>
                <label for="email">Email:<input type="text" id="email" class="text" /></label>
                <label for="message">Message:<textarea id="message"></textarea></label>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send Message" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

PHP (mail.php):

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $recipient = "me@christianselig.com";
    $subject = "Message From Website";
    $headers = "From: " . $email;

    mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "Thanks! The message was sent. :)";

?>
```

Any insight? Thanks so much.

Comment: what does print_r($_POST) show after submitting the form?

Comment: You code is open to malicious use for spam bots etc. Also what is the email in POST?

Comment: You might consider the [http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/redirected](Mail Mime) library. FWIW

Comment: Another alternative: you could try phpMailer: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Comment: Seriously, as Sammaye says, you are **wide** open to being hacked. If the incoming sender email address contains line feeds, it will be treated as a new header, at which point the hacker can do basically anything. PHP's basic `mail()` func is not a good function to use. I **strongly** recommend using one of the alternatives mentioned here in the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forms fields are based on their names not their ids.

replace your :

```
id="(...)"
```

by

```
id="(...)" name="(...)"
```

You should have a look to [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html) which is strongly safer than your current method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a name attribute on your HTML input fields. That's what the form uses to create the indexes in the `$_POST` array. Corrected HTML is below

```
<div class="contact-form">
        <form action="mail.php" method="post">
            <label for="name">Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="text" /></label>
            <label for="email">Email:<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="text" /></label>
            <label for="message">Message:<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea></label>
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send Message" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry for the trivial edit, this is a nice-looking answer, I just wanted to get it out of the "first posts" review queue.

Answer (score 0):

Into my server works, are you sure that in $_POST are set?
If you can't send email assicure you can try to set SMTP to send your email
Try to use something like phpmailer to send email.

In your form for every field you have to put:
 - id="example_id"
 - name="example_name"

Answer (score 0):

you need to give name attribute for each html element . Use below html code:

```
<div class="contact-form">
            <form action="mail.php" method="post">
                <label for="name">Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="text" /></label>
                <label for="email">Email:<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="text" /></label>
                <label for="message">Message:<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea></label>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send Message" />
            </form>
        </div>
```